# lambda expression for Enumerable.Select

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to figure out how to start using linq and lambda expressions.

First of all, if someone could direct me to some good tutorials it will be most appreciated.

Secondly:

I'm trying to select all values which are equal to a specific value using Select method.

I have noticed that select could be defined with a

```
Select<TSource,TResult>(...lambda expression...)
```

Now for this purpose I want to select all the numbers which are equal to 5.

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
IEnumerable<int> res = numbers.Select( x=>5 );
```

This does not work, I just don't understand how this works.
And in what situation should I define `TSource` and `TResult`, and what would they be in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Select()` is used to project each member of the old sequence into a new member of a new sequence. To filter, you use `Where()`:

```
var evens = numbers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0);
var theFiveSequence = numbers.Where(x => x == 5);
```

An example of using `Select()` might be multiplying each number by two:

```
var doubledNumbers = numbers.Select(x => 2*x);
```

You can combine those methods together, too:

```
var doubledNumbersLessThanTen = numbers.Select(x => 2*x).Where(x < 10);
```

Two important things to remember about LINQ:

1. The elements of the base sequence are (almost always) *not* modified. You create new sequences from old sequences.
2. The queries you write are lazily evaluated. You won't get results from them until you use them in a `foreach` loop, or call `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()` etc.

Comment: thanks,
yes iv'e noticed that it Returns and undefined Enumerable , iv'e invoked toList() on it .

what are the TSource and TResult for , just a predestination of the expected source and result , what are they used for ?

Comment: @eran The LINQ extension methods are all generic; `TSource` is the type stored in the source sequence, and `TResult` is the type in the new sequence. You almost never specify them, because the compiler will *infer* them for you.